# Cosa significa "trepestare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Lì ti dissi un giorno, con la sincerità brutale che io trovo soltanto nei momenti di panico o nei momenti di assoluta tranquillità, che ritenevo un errore sposarci, che non credevo di amarti più con piena convinzione. E tu piangesti e **trepestasti**, Shelley, difendendo con caparbietà quella che forse non era più nemmeno per te la persuasione di un passo naturale, né l'obbedienza alle convenienze formali, ma l'approdo di un sogno romantico a cui non volevi rinunciare.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire il verbo "trepestare" in questo brano: non l'ho trovato in nessun dizionario. Questo [sito web](http://kenoms3.altervista.org/altorenotoscano3/longobardismi1.htm) lo definisce come "battere i piedi" e anche come "far confusione", ma non so fino a che punto si tratta di una fonte affidabile. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato di "trepestare"?

Comment: Il termine vuol dire evidentemente "fare rumore" o "far confusione", ma in questo contesto assume il valore particolare di "fare rumore per protesta", quindi forse si potrebbe rendere anche con "fare i capricci" in un italiano più quotidiano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il termine sembra di origine dialettale toscana ed  usato pricipalmente in contesti letterari. Il termine si trova nei vari di [dizionari](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&ei=Vrp3V4ffNcTWsAHWyY_gDg&q=trepestio%20significato&oq=trepestio%20significato&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i10.12796.17176.0.17371.17.17.0.0.0.0.161.2071.2j15.17.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..4.13.1534...41j30i10j0i10i30j0i22i10i30.qq8tuyDUmas) come sostantivo ma non come verbo:

***[Trepestìo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trepestio/) s. m.***

> - ***[forse der. di treppicare, incrociato con calpestìo], tosc. o letter.***  – Confuso calpestìo o altro rumore simile: *Un gran trepestio S’udiva una sera Di zampe e di ruote* (Giusti); *altre schiere sopraggiungevano con un tumultuoso, frenetico t.* (E. Cecchi); *a un tratto gli parve di sentire a destra un t. frettoloso di passi* (Jovine). V. anche trapestio.

***Trapestìo*** s. m. –

> - ***Variante poco com. di trepestio***  (formatasi per un maggiore accostamento a calpestio o perché sentita formata col pref. tra-): *dalla finestra vennero esclamazioni, trapestio* (Pavese); *fin da dietro l’uscio ... udì nell’interno delle stanze un trapestio* (Morante).

Treccani.it

Da *Il cantico*, romanzo di Antonio Beltramelli - Pagina 166 (1906):

> - ***Ad un tratto udii un trepestare rapido di gente in corsa***, uno stioccare di vesti sbattute, un succedersi di brevi voci, onde mi soffermai sogguardando nell' incertezza di ciò che accadeva. Non trascorsero quattro secondi che vidi alcune donne ...

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trepestare%2C%20trepest%C3%ACo&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrepestare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrepest%C3%ACo%3B%2Cc0) trepestare, trepestio.

Comment: Vedo che lo usa anche Carlo Emilio Gadda: https://books.google.es/books?id=0iSO-wetZp8C&dq=%22trepestare%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22trepestare%22.

Comment: Secondo il link che ho messo nella domanda il termine è di origine longobarda ed è in uso nell'Alto Reno e nel Pistoiese.

Comment: Questo [Vocabolario dell'uso toscano di 1863](https://books.google.es/books?id=TM1eAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA997&dq=trepestare+vocabolario&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3yJOV5tTNAhWJ1hQKHWcJD0MQ6AEICjAA#v=onepage&q=trepestare%20vocabolario&f=false) afferma che significa "fare romore".

Comment: Sì, la definizione corrisponde, "confuso calpestio o altro rumore simile".

Comment: Trepestio: http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=trepestio